# Can I set the Max number of rows in unbound DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I find it hard to believe this hasn't been asked before, but it doesn't appear like it has been and my Google searches have all been for naught.

Can I set a maximum number of rows that a DataGridView will allow a user to add? (Like after adding the 10th row it will no longer display the 'new row' row?).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no direct property to do this, but you should be able to accomplish this pretty easily using a combination of the [`AllowUserToAddRows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows.aspx) property, and the [`UserAddedRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.useraddedrow.aspx) event.

The general idea is to add an event handler to check the number of rows against the **Maximum Allowed**, and then set `AllowUserToAddRows = false`

```
public partial class frmGridWithRowLimit : Form
{
    public Int32 MaxRows { get; set; }

    public frmGridWithRowLimit()
    {
        MaxRows = 10;

        InitializeComponent();

        dgRowLimit.UserAddedRow += dgRowLimit_RowCountChanged;
        dgRowLimit.UserDeletedRow += dgRowLimit_RowCountChanged;
    }

    private void dgRowLimit_RowCountChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckRowCount();
    }

    private void CheckRowCount()
    {
        if (dgRowLimit.Rows != null && dgRowLimit.Rows.Count > MaxRows)
        {
            dgRowLimit.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        }
        else if (!dgRowLimit.AllowUserToAddRows)
        {
            dgRowLimit.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You will also want to handle when a user deletes a row to make sure that you allow them to add rows again.

Hope this helps

Cheers,
Josh

Comment: Hey, thanks...Conveniently MaxRows is a constant in my case, don't even have to worry about changing that value.  I'll give this a whirl, then come right back and award you your 25 points! :)

Comment: Beautiful. I was trying something almost identical to this but I had missed several important parts! I'm still surprised that a "max rows" isn't built in though! :)

Comment: @Cpfohl, Probably because it really only works in this particular scenario, and most people use grids with DataBinding. There are a host of issues involved if you are trying to do this with a data bound grid. **It is worth mentioning** that this doesn't take into account rows added programmatically. However, if that isn't going to happen in your scenario, the solution above should be sufficient.

Comment: It's worth noting that when "AllowUserToAddRows" is enabled, the GridView's RowCount property will also be higher because the "add new row" row is also counted.